# How to align table-cells in HTML5?

Tags: html

The attributes valign and align seems to be not supported in html5. 
How to do that now in html5 - with table-cells?

```
<td valign="top" colspan="2" style="height:50px;" > hello world </td>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

With css: `vertical-align` and `text-align` respectively.